# refresh data on the activated route - reroute to it

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I would like to refresh data by routing to the same router again. Angular doesn't activate the ngOnInit component function when there is a second (or more) routing to the current activated route. I would like to enable refreshing the data on the component whenever it is routed (even if it already the activated route). I'm aware that there are few techniques doing it, but I would like to use the RouterEvent and
NavigationEnd technique.I'm aware that I need to set the onSameUrlNavigation in the 
RouteModule. 
For some reason, I can't reach the scenario I want.
See my code:
This is the event that fired when clicking on the button (clicking twice on the button should route twice to the same component):

```
openMapTool(item: MapToolsItem)
{
   this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { <Name of router outlet>: ['SomePath', { param1: value1}] }}],);
  return false;
}
```

This is the component (see below - "SomeComponent") that is related to the "SomePath" path - the component that should be routed twice:

```
 ngOnInit() {
this.subs.push(this.route.events.pipe(
  filter(e => e instanceof RouterEvent && e instanceof NavigationEnd),
).subscribe(e => 
  {
    this.doSomething(e.paramMap);
  }));
```

This is the module that contains the path of the "SomePath" :

```
const routes: Routes = [

{ path: 'SomePath', component: SomeComponent, outlet: 'SomeRouterOutlet'}];

@NgModule({
imports: [
RouterModule.forChild(routes),
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation:'reload'})]})
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your components are cached and then re-used. Check if a `RouteReuseStrategy` is defined in your app.module.ts. If this is the case, you should programmatically clear the component from the cache of the `RouteReuseStrategy`  class.

```
app.module.ts

providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: <class name>}
```

To access the class defined in `app.module.ts`, use `Router.routeReuseStrategy`

Answer (score 0):

You could try subscribing to routePrams and take action accordingly.

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params =>
  // Do something
});
```